# Sketch the graph of the function $f(x) =\frac{(x+1)^3} {x^2 - x+1}$

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I tried to follow the rules of sketching a graph, I found the intersection with the ox and oy in (0,1)and (-1,0) and I think that the oblique asymptote is y=x+4. What about the vertical ones? The roots of the denominator are complex ones. Can we say these are asymptotes?.. The first derivative is pretty hard to find roots of. How can I sketch its graph, please?

Comment: If the denominator of $f$ doesn't vanish, $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ and there is no vertical asymptote.

Comment: OK, I get it now

Comment: Some additional elements in the answer below.

Comment: $f'(x)=\frac{(x-2)^2 (x+1)^2}{\left(x^2-x+1\right)^2}$. Hope this can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$f(x) =\frac{(x+1)^3} {x^2 - x+1} = x + 4 + \frac{6x - 3}{x^2-x+1}.$$

As $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{6x - 3}{x^2-x+1} = 0$, $y=x+4$ is indeed an asymptote of $f$. Also the sign of $\frac{6x - 3}{x^2-x+1}$ is the one of $6x-3$ as $x^2-x+1$ is always positive. So $f$ crosses its asymptote at $x = 1/2$, is above it for $x > 1/2$ and below it for $x < 1/2$.

You can also find where the maximal vertical distance between $f$ and its asymptote is by vanishing the derivative of $g(x)=\frac{6x - 3}{x^2-x+1}$. You'll find two symmetric values about $x=1/2$.

Some elements to start a decent plot...

Comment: How can I see that symmetry about x=1/2 just by vanishing the derivative?

Comment: Yes by vanishing the derivative of $g$ and by noticing that $g(x) = 3\frac{x - \frac{1}{2}}{\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 +\frac{3}{4}}$.

Comment: Vanishing it, we ll get a critical point. The symmetry axis always passes through it?

Comment: No, vanishing it, we'll get the points at the maximum distance from the asymptote.

Comment: After that, how can I sketch the symmetric part of the graph for x>1/2? Wouldn't I have to seek the inflexion points or something..?

Comment: Graphing a mapping is a question of taste! Depending on what your teacher is asking for, you can add more topics. I let you decide on this question. You could find inflexion points, tangent where the mapping crosses the asymptote, etc...